# Evaluate the integral $2\pi \int^1 _0 |e^{2\pi i t}-1||e^{2\pi i t}| dt$

Tags: complex-analysis

My attempt is to expand it into cos and sin forms, but it only makes the problem harder to solve. What should I do.

Comment: $| e^{iy} | = 1$ will help simplify your problem. Also, $| e^{2 \pi i t} - 1 | = \sqrt{(\cos(2 \pi t) - 1)^{2} + \sin^{2}(2 \pi t)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\Bbb e ^{2\pi \Bbb i t}| = 1$, we may forget about it and focus on

$$\int \limits _0 ^1 \sqrt {(\cos 2 \pi t - 1)^2 + \sin^2 2 \pi t} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^1 \sqrt {\cos^2 2 \pi t + \sin^2 2 \pi t - 2 \cos 2 \pi t + 1} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^1 \sqrt {\cos^2 2 \pi t + \sin^2 2 \pi t - 2 \cos 2 \pi t + 1} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^1 \sqrt {2 - 2 \cos 2 \pi t} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^1 \sqrt {2 \cdot 2 \sin^2 \pi t} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^1 2 |\sin \pi t| \ \Bbb d t = 2 \int \limits _0 ^1 \sin \pi t \ \Bbb d t = 2 \frac {-\cos \pi t} \pi \Bigg| _0 ^1 = \frac 4 \pi .$$

Multiplying this by the $2 \pi$ found in front of the integral gives the answer: $8$.

I have used the known trigonometric identity $2 \sin^2 a = 1 - \cos 2 a$; the modulus has disappeared from the integral because $\sin \pi t \ge 0$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** use the fact that $|e^{iy}|=1$ and factor $|e^{\pi it}|$ out from the remaining term. Now you can use the fact that $$\sin(t)=\frac{1}{2i}\cdot (e^{it}-e^{-it}).$$

Answer (score 0):

First, $|e^{2\pi it}| = 1$. For the other piece, consider the absolute value of
$$(e^{i\theta} - 1)^2 = e^{i\theta} (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} - 2).$$
Hint: $(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} - 2)$ is real.